# How to make ruby class callable like in Trailblazer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I write class that can be called automatically with parentheses like a method (for example, by internally invoking `#execute`) through next syntax:
`MyModule::Class.(*params)` or
`MyModule::Class(*params)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is *very* easy to just try this out, because Ruby will *literally* tell you what you need to do.

You say you want to able to write `MyModule::Class.(*params)`, so you simply do *exactly that*:

```ruby
MyModule::Class.(*params)
```

And Ruby tells you what you are missing:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `call' for MyModule::Class:Class)
```

So, as you can see, Ruby tells us that we are missing a method named `call` in the singleton class of `MyModule::Class`, so let's just define that method:

```ruby
module MyModule
  def Class.call(*params)
    puts "Method `#{__callee__}` called with params #{params.inspect}"
  end
end

MyModule::Class.(1, 'two', :three, [[], [], [], []], { five: :six })
# Method `call` called with params [1, "two", :three, [[], [], [], []], {:five=>:six}]
```

So, the secret sauce here is that `foo.(bar, baz)` is syntactic sugar for `foo.call(bar, baz)`.

For the second example, we can do the exact same thing:

```ruby
MyModule::Class(*params)
```

And again:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `Class' for MyModule:Module)
```

So, in this case, Ruby is telling us that we need a method named `Class` on the singleton class of `MyModule`.

You are simply calling a method named `Class` on the object `MyModule`. It is, in fact, *exactly the same* as if you had written `MyModule.Class(*params)`.

```ruby
def MyModule.Class(*params)
  puts "Method `#{__callee__}` called with params #{params.inspect}"
end

MyModule::Class(1, 'two', :three, [[], [], [], []], { five: :six })
# Method Class called with params [1, "two", :three, [[], [], [], []], {:five=>:six}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define method `call`

```
class User
  def self.call(arg)
    "got arg #{arg}"
  end
end

User.(1) # => "got arg 1"
```